# jqgrid change column sort parameter (sidx) value

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a column in my grid named "FullName"  when I click on it to sort it sends back to the server sidx:FullName.

What I would like is to be able to say " on this column on sort send back the value 'x' "

so in the above case I would click on column "FullName" and it would send to server sidx:LastName.

The reason for this is that I take that value and create a query based on it, however the property "FullName" is a generated value

```
public string FullNmae
    { 
       get{ return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName; }
    }
```

so "FullName" doesn't exist in my db.  I need to search on the "LastName" property.

Comment: you can use for example `index: "LastName, FirstName"` or for the column `FullName`. Additionally you can just analyse the value of `sidx` which you get *on the server side* and use `ORDER BY LastName ASC, FirstName ASC` or `ORDER BY LastName DESC, FirstName DESC` depend on the value of `sord` parameter if `sidx` is `FullName`.

Comment: @Oleg Can something like what you suggested here be used to do multiple group sorting? ex Order by Lastname and then by First name?

Comment: Yes, it's what I mean. It will be mostly close to what the user want if he click on the column header of the column `FullName`. One can use `index` on the client side, but the possibilities which you have on the server side in you C# code are more powerful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your `index: LastName` which should then pass that value in your post when sorting on that column.